# QListWidget on freemantle

Tags: python, qt, maemo, n900

I have a problem with QListWidget on freemantle (maemo, n900).

I want to use two QListWidget on same window and allow the user to pick on number in each window.

When the user use the second QListWidget, the "blue" color on it disparear.
How to change the color of a item selected in QListWidget which is not active ?

Comment: It is "Fremantle" and NOT "Freemantle".

Answer (score 2):

Kind of a hack, but you can change the `QPallete` of both `QListWidgets` so that the inactive color is the same as the active color.

http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qpalette.html#ColorGroup-enum

There is code sample here: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/17922-two-qlistwidgets that might be of use to you.  I don't have access to any mobile Qt-enabled devices to test it out but it should work in theory.